# Running function in a loop concurrently

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, while-loop, concurrency

I have this javascript loop which is fairly straight forward to understand. It essentially calls `infoGetter()` in a loop. However, the problem is it calls `infoGetter()` 20 times at once. I only want there to be always `3` `infoGetters()` working at any one point in time (unless we reached the while loop condition).

```
var min = 1;
var limit = 1000;
var myId = 12345;
while (min < limit) {
    var max = min + 50;
    infoGetter(myId, min, max);
    min = max;
}


function infoGetter(myId, min, max) {

    return $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "get-info.php",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            myId: myId,
            min: min,
            max: max
        },
        success: function(data) {
            /* to stuff here (not important to this question) */
        }
    });

}
```

**How I want the script to work:**

1. In the loop it calls `infoGetter(myId, 1, 51);` and waits for return value in the background
2. Increases min, it calls `infoGetter(myID, 51, 102);` and waits for return value in background
3. Increases min, it calls `infoGetter(myID, 102, 153);` and waits for return value in background

Now as soon as one of the the `infoGetter()` gets a return value it calls it again with the new parameters (as there always needs to be `3` `infoGetter()`'s running at one time unless it reaches the while loop condition). The new parameters will obviously be the new `myId`, `min`, `max` values that we updated, as we are changing `min` and `max` in the loop.

Where the `3` can be a different number like `5`. So we can have 5 `infoGetter()`'s running at one time.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a function which calls `infoGetter`, and recursively calls itself if there are more requests that need to be made by chaining onto the ajax call returned by `infoGetter`. Then call that function 3 times, so that whenever a request succeeds, it calls `makeRequest` again:

```
let min = 1;
const limit = 1000;
const myId = 12345;
const makeRequest = () => {
  const max = min + 50;
  infoGetter(myId, min, max)
    .then(() => {
      if (min < limit) {
        makeRequest();
      }
    });
  min = max;
};

makeRequest();
makeRequest();
makeRequest();
```

or

```
const maximumConcurrentRequests = 3;
for (let i = 0; i < maximumConcurrentRequests; i++) {
  makeRequest();
}
```

If you want the process to continue even if a request fails, `catch` the Promise before calling `.then` on it:

```
infoGetter(myId, min, max)
  .catch(() => void 0)
  .then(() => {
```

Or, in full:

```
let min = 1;
const limit = 1000;
const myId = 12345;
const makeRequest = () => {
  const max = min + 50;
  infoGetter(myId, min, max)
    .catch(() => void 0)
    .then(() => {
      if (min < limit) {
        makeRequest();
      }
    });
  min = max;
};
```

Live demo, where `infoGetter` is simulated using a Promise which resolves after a random number between 0 and 5 seconds:

```js
const infoGetter = () => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, Math.random() * 5000));

let min = 1;
const limit = 1000;
const myId = 12345;
const makeRequest = () => {
  console.log('making request for', min);
  const max = min + 50;
  infoGetter(myId, min, max)
    .catch(() => void 0)
    .then(() => {
      if (min < limit) {
        makeRequest();
      }
    });
  min = max;
};

const maximumConcurrentRequests = 3;
for (let i = 0; i < maximumConcurrentRequests; i++) {
  makeRequest();
}
```

If you also want to detect when all requests are done, put the initial promises into an array, return the Promises from recursive calls, and call `Promise.all` on the array:

```js
const infoGetter = () => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, Math.random() * 5000));

let min = 1;
const limit = 500;
const myId = 12345;
const makeRequest = () => {
  console.log('making request for', min);
  const thisMin = min;
  const max = min + 50;
  min = max;
  return infoGetter(myId, thisMin, max)
    .catch(() => void 0)
    .then(() => {
      if (min < limit) {
        return makeRequest();
      }
    });
};

const maximumConcurrentRequests = 3;
Promise.all(
  Array.from(
    { length: maximumConcurrentRequests },
    makeRequest
  )
)
  .then(() => {
    console.log('All done');
  });
```

Comment: Can you show me how you do the second method fully?

Comment: It's exactly the same except with that `.catch(() => void 0)` line added in between.

Comment: So when you call `makeRequest()` is there any instance where `min`, `max` are duplicates? Or will everything still work out in order?

Comment: No,`min` is incremented synchronously on every call, so each request will be different

Comment: Oh I see, at what point in the code do I know that no more`infoGetters()` need to be conducted (hence, we have finished calling all the possibile `infoGetters()`. Because I want to basically update a html id called `progress` and set that htl value to `All info has been grabbed`

Comment: You said that */* to stuff here (not important to this question) */*, so it sounded like you didn't care about what happens when requests succeed, only that they go in order. If you *do* care about when request succeed, then use `Promise.all` on an array of the initial Promises, and return each `infoGetter` Promise in `makeRequest`

Comment: Did you find any of the code snippets in the answer helpful? You can press "Run code snippet" to see them working